# size = 0 when try to upload image to server by php and android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i try to upload image to phpmyadmin server but in every time i get same error first error : Notice: Undefined index: image_path in /storage/ssd2/750/2564750/public_html/hi.php on line 12
Your Image Has Been Uploaded.

image is uploaded to server but its size =0 "zero"

php code

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
 $DefaultId = 0;

 $ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];

 $ImageName = $_POST['image_name'];

 $GetOldIdSQL ="SELECT id FROM UploadImageToServer ORDER BY id ASC";

 $Query = mysqli_query($conn,$GetOldIdSQL);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){

 $DefaultId = $row['id'];
 }

 $ImagePath = "images/$DefaultId.png";

 $ServerURL = "https://xxxxx.000webhostapp.com/$ImagePath";

 $InsertSQL = "insert into UploadImageToServer (image_path,image_name) values ('$ServerURL','$ImageName')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){

 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));

 echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 echo "Not Uploaded";
 }

?>
```

my database (id,    image_path,image_name) both path and name datatype is text

i use postman to test my test like the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JDWO.png

Comment: Ummm `$_FILES` ? There seem to be more than one or two errors here, check the manual on [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: can you explain what is this main ? i beigner in php

Comment: and i want this code to android application

Comment: Maybe you can pay someone for this work.

Comment: It means you're fundamentally handling file uploads incorrectly; answering this question would require effectively repeating everything in the manual on file uploads... so it's better to just cut out the middle-man and point you to the manual.

Comment: is the file is wrong so much?

Comment: This PHP code  is pure security horror so dont go live with it. Because of SQL injection (time based blind SQL injections), not validating a upload is a image so other files can also be uploaded... Programming secure image upload systems can be pretty challenging